# Combining binary and ordinal variables in a single scale for use as dependent variable

Tags: scales

My brain is failing to come up with the right search terms to remind myself how to do this...

I have two variables, one indicating a yes/no decision and the second indicating the respondent's confidence in their answer on a scale of 1-7, which I'll probably just treat it as continuous. I would like to combine the two into one scale with high-confidence "no" answers on one extreme and high-confidence "yes" answers on the other. Replacing the 0s in the dummy with -1 and multiplying by the confidence variable is straightforward but leaves a hole in the middle of the scale.

I'm intending to use this as a dependent variable.

Comment: If you're sure that's meaningful, just removed the hole.

Answer (score 1):

A hole in the middle of the scale isn't necessarily a problem. It depends on what you're doing with the values.

You *could* consider the combined scale as having originally been a symmetric equispaced14 point scale without an exact 0 in it, in which case you *might* code it as -13,-11,-9,-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7,9,11,13, but I don't necessarily see that -7...-1,1,...7 should be a major issue.

How do you plan to treat this DV?

As ordered categorical? (then it doesn't matter which you choose)...

As numeric*? (then it depends on how you think the gaps behave as you go from - to + categories)

*(say as interval scale if you're thinking in Stevens typology)

Comment: Your first suggestion makes a lot of sense, and fortunately these models are really only concerned with significance and sign rather than the actual coefficient values.

Yes, this is for use as a DV. I'm going to treat it as an interval scale because, again, I really don't care what the coefficients are, so keeping things simple and robust seems the better part of valor.

Comment: Sign shouldn't be impacted by the presence or absence of the gap (it's *just* possible, but it would take an odd circumstance to make it happen); similarly with significance. If it were to make a difference either way, you'd have to say your results were not robust to a pretty minor decision and so I'd put little stock in significance that could disappear if the other choice were made, and little stock in a sign that might change if the other choice were made. Fortunately, that situation's highly unlikely --- but also important to know if it were to happen (choose one, sure, but ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... if you're investigating threats to your conclusions, that would be something to consider looking at).